# wp_set_post_terms not updating with WP Cron Event

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-cron, terms

I have a jobs board custom post type (`job_listings`) with a taxonomy (`cvl_job_status`) attached with various tags assigned, namely; Live, Filled and Expired.

Each job post has a custom field (`cvl_job_expires`) with an expiry date.

Using a WP Cron Event I want to change the taxonomy tag from Live to Expired if today's date is greater than the saved expiry date.

Can't see what's wrong with the following code, first and foremost `$post_ids` is returning an empty array.

can anyone help?

TIA

```
add_action('cvl_job_status_cron', 'cvl_mark_as_expired');

function cvl_mark_as_expired() {

  global $post;

  $post_ids = get_posts( 
    [
      'post_type' => 'job_listing',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'no_found_rows' => true,
      'fields' => 'ids', //again, for performance
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'cvl_job_status',
          'field' => 'id',
          'terms' => 158, // ID of 'Live' tag
        )
      )
    ] 
  );

  var_dump($post_ids); // this returns as empty??

  foreach($post_ids as $post_id) {

    $key = 'cvl_job_expires'; // custom field name
    $expire_date = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true); // Expiry Date saved as (d M y)
    $todays_date = date('d M y'); // get todays date

    if ($expire_date < $todays_date) {

      $taxonomy = 'cvl_job_status';
      $tag      = array( 159 );  // ID of 'Expired' tag

      wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $tag, $taxonomy );

      //  I have also tried this with
      //  wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $tag, $taxonomy );

    }

  }

}
```

(The `cvl_job_status_cron` event is running and this function `cvl_mark_as_expired` is attached to it as shown in the Wp Cron-Events Plug-In)

Comment: What sort of debugging have you done? Have you verified that `$post_ids` gets populated? Have you verified the values for `$expire_date` and `$todays_date` are correct? Have you verified that it passes the `if` condition and `wp_set_post_terms` is called? Have you looked at what `wp_set_post_terms` returns?

Comment: Sorry - possibly the most important thing I forgot to add - $post_ids is returning an empty array() !!

Comment: `field` should be `term_id` in a tax query, not `id`.

Comment: Thank you, `$post_ids` is still empty though I'm afraid - no errors or notices being thrown up

Comment: Try changing `get_posts` to `new WP_Query`, then you can inspect `$post_ids->request` after the query is run and you'll see the SQL being sent to the database.

Comment: Thank you @Milo using WP Query go it working! Full code has been updated in the post in case it is useful to anyone

Comment: Can't see where to tag you as the answerer?

Comment: you can add your working code as an answer and the system will let you accept it after a short waiting period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now Working with Wp Query - Thanks to Milo in the comments

```
add_action('cvl_job_status_cron', 'cvl_mark_as_expired');

function cvl_mark_as_expired() {

  global $post;

  $args = array(
    'post_type'              => array( 'job_listing' ),
    'posts_per_page'         => '-1',
    'fields'                 => 'ids',
    'tax_query'              => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'taxonomy'         => 'cvl_job_status',
        'terms'            => 'live',
        'field'            => 'slug',
        'include_children' => false,
      ),
    ),
  );

// $post_ids = get_posts($args);

  $post_ids = new WP_Query( $args );

  if ( $post_ids->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $post_ids->have_posts() ) {

    $post_ids->the_post();

    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    $key          = 'cvl_job_expires'; // custom field anme
    $expire_date  = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true); // Now saved as Unix Timestamp
    $todays_date  = time(); // get todays date

      if ($expire_date < $todays_date) {

        $taxonomy = 'cvl_job_status';
        $tag      = array( 159 );  // 'Expire' tag id is 159

        wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $tag, $taxonomy );

      }

    }

  }

}
```